# Can't run rails server as daemon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, daemon, mongrel

I'm using rails 2.3.2 and when I run script/server -d, the only output I get is

=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.2 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000

which is fine.  But when I check for anything running on port 3000, i get nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Check TYPE "http://0.0.0.0:3000"   or "http://localhost:3000" and what you get in a browser also paste what you get on console.

Comment: Tell us more about the hosting environment you're trying to run this in. I remember trying to run rails on 1and1 shared hosting years ago, and anytime it started up, it would automatically be killed. So ... yeah ... hosting environment.

Comment: I'm having a similar thing happen, rails 2.3.5, old legacy app

script/server works; script/server -d has the same result, prints 'starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000/' but ps shows nothing and attemps to connect find nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If the mongrel server has started, which appears to be the case, it's probably a firewall issue which you would need to manage via iptables.

From the local machine try to connect to localhost:3000.

For example `curl http://localhost:3000` or `telnet localhost 3000`

If this wasn't the problem and the rails logs are uneventful, you could also have a look in various system logs such as /var/log/messages or /var/log/secure which may hint you on what's going on.